# RAM incompatibility issues between T-Force Team Vulcan and Corsair Vengeance

Tags: windows-10, memory, bsod, compatibility

In my system, I decided to get a 2-pack of T-Force Team Vulcan 8GB DDR4 3000MHz (something like [this](https://www.youritdelivered.com/team-vulcan-z-16gb-red-heatsink-2-x-8gb-ddr4-2666mhz-dimm-system-memory-tlzrd416g2666hc18hdc01/?CAWELAID=620008670000522832&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=72196644464&CATCI=pla-796024662840&CATARGETID=620008670000493784&CADevice=c&gclid=CjwKCAjwgbLzBRBsEiwAXVIygIv5JWmB5j-T75JWDwm8ofn4Mi-u2b2wUSPRYKgtlQZAfEQ56nPciBoCgWoQAvD_BwE)), but, as a result of a discount I found, I also added in 2 sticks Corsair Vengeance DDR4 (also 8GB, 3000MHz) - 2 sets of [these](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Corsair-CMK8GX4M1A2400C16-Vengeance-Performance-Desktop/dp/B01ARHBBPS/ref=asc_df_B01ARHBBPS/?tag=googshopuk-21&linkCode=df0&hvadid=310762440393&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=3409281014496505867&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9046620&hvtargid=pla-329825128976&psc=1&th=1&psc=1) (I purchased the two sticks separately; am unsure if this makes a difference in terms of batch or something).

I was OK with doing this, because common sense (and some research) implies that there is nothing inherently preventing these from working together, since (by my understanding) to the motherboard (an [ASUS B450M-A](https://www.asus.com/uk/Motherboards/PRIME-B450M-A/)) RAM is just RAM, so given the same type, size and speed, they should work together. After putting them in, everything booted fine, and according to the BIOS the motherboard recognised the speed, type, make, size, and everything, and all looks fine/as expected there.

However, since assembling the build (running Windows 10, 10.0.18363 Build 18363), I have been experiencing multiple non-negligible (seemingly) hardware-/RAM-related issues, including:

- Apps, especially more RAM-consuming ones (such as Chrome, Affinity Designer, Webstorm/JetBrains IDE) spontaneously closing - not crashing, freezing, 'Not Responding', etc. - just closing randomly without warning or saving work.
- Very frequent (near-daily) Windows BSODs, with memory-related stop codes, e.g `page_fault_in_nonpaged_area`, `critical_process_died` and `video_scheduler_internal` are very common.
- Inconsistent functionality within apps, e.g Google Chrome often giving `Aw, snap` and page crash errors, sometimes with no trigger: I am just scrolling on a page, reading an article or something, and the page gets replaced with the error message.

As aforementioned, the motherboard recognised them fine, and there is no apparent technical limitation for why these should not work: there is no difference in the RAM except for the brand of two of them being different. I am not *certain* that it is the RAM which is misbehaving, but given the exact combination of symptoms (I have no issues with CPU, storage, graphics, etc.) and the issue persisting after various graphics- and HDD driver updates, as well as a fresh Windows reinstall, I have reason to believe that it is in fact the memory at fault.

Is this a possible issue, or am I missing something? If this is something that can happen with RAM, is it intended/known, or is it a fault with my specific model? Is there anything that can be done about the situation?

Answer (score 0):

These are some things you should check.

1. Confirm that the two Vulcan sticks are in the same bank (I believe that would be a black and a gray slot on one side of the 4 slots) while the Corsair sticks are in the other bank (the other side gray and black slots).

   - if that is not the case, change to this configuration and check for reproduction of faults.
2. Boot into your BIOS (the F1 key sequence usually at a restart) and complete a random-address RAM test (look for it, or just do the full RAM test).

   - If this is successful the RAM sticks are probably good.
3. Take out one of the pairs and work with 8 GB RAM for some time (say, about three times the average period your system takes to hit a fault with all of 16 GB RAM loaded on the motherboard).

   - If this stops reproducing the problem then change to 8 GB with the other two sticks and confirm they are working too.

If **all** of these checks complete without error indications, test your primary hard disk (go back to the BIOS diagnostics for that).